# expect ssh reg_ex for remote prompt

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I have an shell script which uses expect to launch a ssh session to another server and list a directory.  It works fine but my question is what is the best way to handle remote prompts after logging in?  For example, here is what I have so far:

```
# Wait for the prompt on a remote ssh server
-re "\[%|>|\$|#\] $" {
        send "ls -1t /home/user/\r"
        expect {
                "*not found" {
                    puts "\nDirectory not found\n"
                    exp_continue
                 }
                 timeout { puts "\ntimeout happened\n" }
                 -re "\[%|>|\$|#\] $" {
                    puts "Exiting..."
                    send "exit\r"
                    return
                 }
        }
}
```

So, after a successful login the expect script waits for the prompt before sending the `ls -1t /home/user/` command. The prompt can be different depending how how the `ssh` destination is setup.  So far I'm checking for

```
-re "\[%|>|\$|#\] $"
```

prompts handled so far....

```
%
>
$
#
```

I would like to make this as generic as possible so I know the destination `ssh` server is ready to receive the `ls -1t /home/user/` command.

Is there a better way to do this or should I add more cases to the reg_ex in my expect script?

I've also tried `-re ". $"` but this doesn't work

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.